# Using displacement field vs. electric field to calculate curl of magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

So let's say we have a medium with polarization $\vec{P} = \gamma \nabla \times E$, with no free currents or charges.

So we know that $H = \frac{1}{\mu_0} B - M$ , $D = \epsilon_0 E+P$ and $\nabla \ \times H =\mu_0 J_{free}+\frac{\partial D}{\partial t} $ here reduces to $\nabla \ \times H =\frac{\partial D}{\partial t} $

So since there is no free current I mistakenly thought that $\nabla \times B = \mu_0 J + \frac{\partial E}{\partial t}$ reducing to here $\nabla \times B = \frac{\partial E}{\partial t}$ but if I say that

$$\nabla \times B = \mu_0 \nabla \times H = \mu_0 \frac{\partial D}{\partial t} = \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \frac{\partial E}{\partial t} + \mu_0 \frac{\partial P}{\partial t} \not= \frac{\partial E}{\partial t}$$

so why do I need to use the displacement field here? this is like saying there is a current due to the polarization but what is this current? what am I missing here?

Comment: Such polarization law is unphysical, because curl of electric field is proportional to rate of change of magnetic field. Magnetic field and its rate of change in time has no objective orientation in space, it is assigned by convention to conform to the usual hand rules. But orientation of polarization is an objective physical state, it cannot follow changes in human conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course there is current due to changes in polarization. For polarization to change, charged particles have to change positions, and this motion means there is electric current.

In a dielectric with no magnetization, total current can be expressed as
$$
\mathbf J = \frac{\partial \mathbf P}{\partial t}.
$$

In a magnetic medium with no electric polarization, total current can be expressed as
$$
\mathbf J = \nabla \times \mathbf M.
$$

There is no universal formula for total current, it depends on the medium. In magnetic conductor in ohmic regime, total current is

$$
\mathbf J = \nabla \times \mathbf M + \sigma \mathbf E.
$$

Comment: I see, I guess time to go back and read ch.7 in Griffiths. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

By your account, you have the following constitutive relations:
$$ = ε_0 + γ∇×, \hspace 1em  = μ_0( + ),$$
and I'm assuming $γ$ is a constant. From the Maxwell equation
$$\frac{∂}{∂t} + ∇× =  ⇒ ∇× = -\frac{∂}{∂t},$$
so we can write
$$ = ε_0 - γ\frac{∂}{∂t}.$$

You're assuming $ = $, from which it follows:
$$∇× - \frac{∂}{∂t} =  =  ⇒ ∇× = \frac{∂}{∂t}.$$
Thus, upon substitution of $$, we have:
$$∇× = μ_0 ∇× + μ_0 ∇× = μ_0 \frac{∂}{∂t} + μ_0 ∇×,$$
and upon further substitution of $$, we have (assuming $γ$ is constant):
$$\frac{∂}{∂t} = ε_0 \frac{∂}{∂t} - γ \frac{∂^2}{∂t^2},$$
which, after applying $μ_0 ε_0 = (1/c)^2$, results in the formula:
$$∇× = μ_0 ∇× + μ_0 ∇× = \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{∂}{∂t} - μ_0 γ \frac{∂^2}{∂t^2} + μ_0 ∇×.$$

With the constitutive relations, you can eliminate one field from each pair $(,)$ and $(,)$.

The final equation can be arranged as:
$$∇× - \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{∂}{∂t} = μ_0\left(∇× - γ \frac{∂^2}{∂t^2}\right),$$
so, there's an effective current given in the parentheses on the right, arising ultimately from the constitutive relations. Bringing back the $-$ Maxwell equation, we also have
$$\frac{∂^2}{∂t^2} = \frac{∂}{∂t}\left(\frac{∂}{∂t}\right) = \frac{∂}{∂t}\left(-∇×\right) = -∇×\left(\frac{∂}{∂t}\right).$$
Assuming, again, that $γ$ is constant,
$$∇× - \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{∂}{∂t} = μ_0 ∇×\left( + γ \frac{∂}{∂t}\right).$$
So, the effective current, by virtue of being a curl, is divergence-free.

Comment: My question is more of, why is it incorrect to say that $\nabla \times B = \mu_0 J + \frac{\partial E}{\partial t}$ then set J = 0 and get  $\nabla \times B = \frac{\partial E}{\partial t}$. What is missing here physics wise that makes this result incorrect, why do I need to look at the displacement field and H to get the correct answer?

Comment: The relation ∇× - ∂/∂t =  is actually the more fundamental one, not any involving (,). So, really, your question boils down to why so, and why are there even two sets of fields in the first place. But given that, then from the relations  = ε₀ + ,  = μ₀( + ), it follows that ∇× - (1/c)² ∂/∂t = μ₀( + ∇× + ∂/∂t) and (from ∇· = ρ) ∇· = (ρ - ∇·)/ε₀. Setting  =  (and even ρ = 0), you still have the effective current ∇× + ∂/∂t and charge -∇· arising from the magnetization  and polarization . So, setting  =  won't give you ∇× = (1/c)² ∂/∂t.

Comment: For the other question: why two sets ... that's almost a universal property of physical systems. One set describes system configurations and their derivatives (for mechanics if time t is the only independent variable), or gradients (for fields if spatial coordinates (x,y,z) and time t are). The other set describe dynamics. The connection between the sets ("constitutive relations") characterizes the system. Here (φ,,,) are "kinematic" or "configuration", (ρ,,,) "dynamic". The (,)-(,) relation is only trivial for the vacuum; but not even always there (e.g. curved spacetime).